Changed data size error
I'm building a custom Rust library for Solana smart contracts that utilizes C types and therefore calls sol_invoke_signed_c. However, I'm encountering this error "program other than the account's owner changed the size of the account data" on mainnet, which doesn't occur during local testing. Any insights on why this might be happening?

Why the error happens:

Account Owner Problem: Only the account's owner can change its data. If another program tries to do it, you get this error.

Data Size Issue: Solana accounts have a fixed size. If your program or another program tries to change the size, it will fail.

Testing Differences: Local testing isn't as strict as mainnet, so some issues only show up on mainnet.


Here is the way to fix it :

Check Account Ownership:
Make sure the account being modified is owned by the program trying to change it.

Preallocate Enough Space:
When creating the account, set its size big enough to handle all future data updates.

Set Account Permissions:
Ensure that the account passed to sol_invoke_signed_c is marked as writable.

Test on Testnet:
Test on Solana’s testnet instead of just localnet to catch these mainnet-specific issues early.

Simulate Transactions:
Use the Solana CLI or tools to simulate your transaction before sending it to mainnet. This can help spot issues.


